# Can't position text inside of text_box widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do I position text in the text_box widger? I've tried something like:

```
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("1.1", "Document number 1")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("2.2", "LOREM IPSUMCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")
show_both_documents_text_box.config(state='disabled')
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Both of texts are displayed one after one

What I'd like to achievie, is something like this:

```
                                       Document 1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.


                                       Document 2
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: how exactly do you want them to be positioned?

Comment: Just added visualisation to the question

Comment: When the second `.insert(..)` is called, index `2.2` is beyond the last index of the text widget, so the content will be added at the end instead.

Comment: Your problem is caused by trying to insert text into a empty `Text` object. In other words you are trying to insert text after the `tk.end` of available insertion positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index must represent an existing position in the document. If you want text on multiple lines, you must insert newlines (`"\n"`) at the appropriate places.

```
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Document number 1\n")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Document number 2\n")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n")
```

If you want the data centered, you can apply a tag with the proper alignment.

```
show_both_documents_text_box.tag_configure("center", justify="center")

show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Document number 1\n", "center")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n", "center")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Document number 2\n", "center")
show_both_documents_text_box.insert("end", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\n\n", "center")
```

[image: screenshot]